# How to run vstest using Linux agent in azure Release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

**Problem statement:**
I have specflow tests written in .NetCore and used to run on windows based agents. Now I need to run these tests in linux agent.

I have used build pipeline with windows based agent to build the artifacts. Then in the Release pipeline I have added the vstest Task and Ubuntu agent as below

***Agent Pool:*** Azure Pipelines

***Agent Specfication:*** Ubuntu 20.04

When I run the pipeline the vstest task gave error as below

*This task is supported only on Windows agents and cannot be used on other platforms*

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Use `dotnet test`. Like the error message said, you can't use VS Test on Linux.

Comment: @DanielMann There is a way to use vstest. Add dotnet Test task and in the 'Command' type select 'custom' instead of 'test'. In custom command 'vstest' can be given. It works. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a work around to achieve this.

Add dotnet test Task and change the command to 'custom' instead of test and custom command as 'vstest'. The configuration looks as below

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet custom'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    projects: '**/Tests.dll'
    custom: vstest
    arguments: '--logger:trx;logfilename=TEST.xml'
  timeoutInMinutes: 120
```

Comment: I wish I could give more than 1 upvote!  I had been trying quite a bit of trial and error but this did the trick.  I am just starting out and this helped out a lot.  Thank you!

Comment: Don't think will work with batchingBasedOnAgentsOption

Answer (score 0):

You can't use vstest on Linux. vstest requires that either Visual Studio is installed or that you have the VS Test Platform installed.

If you want to use vstest you can [change the Agent Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to Windows.